# Use ansible.builtin in ansible 2.9

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I'm using ansible 2.9.7 and `ansible.builtin.copy` (or another builtin) is working correctly, but all I can find in the documentation is that I need to use builtin in the 2.10 migration.

I wonder if you have any information on whether it's OK to use builtins in 2.9 (or earlier).
Thank you for your help.

Comment: 2.9 was the transition version for the module namespaces.

Comment: In other words: you cannot use the `<namespace>.<collection>.<module>` notation in ansible < 2.9. You may use that notation in ansible >= 2.9 but you can usually still use the short module name as long as there are no name conflicts in the installed collections. I personally never used the long notation for copy

Comment: Short answer: don't use Ansible 2.9, it is EOL since last year: https://access.redhat.com/support/policy/updates/ansible-engine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Introduction

In Ansible `2.9` and prior, engine and modules were in the Ansible project.
In Ansible `2.10` the project has been [restructured](https://www.ansible.com/blog/thoughts-on-restructuring-the-ansible-project) (main reason seems to be the difficulty to manage core engine and all modules in the same code base) into

- Ansible language, runtime and [builtin plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/index.html#plugins-in-ansible-builtin) in [`ansible-base`](https://pypi.org/project/ansible-base/), that has been renamed later to [`ansible-core`](https://pypi.org/project/ansible-core/) (starting at version `2.11`).
- Ansible Collections of modules and plugins managed in Ansible Galaxy and follow their own lifecycle.

Plus a third artefact called **Ansible community package** that is an Ansible installation including [`ansible-core`](https://pypi.org/project/ansible-core/) plus community curated Collections. It is available as [`ansible`](https://pypi.org/project/ansible/).

So starting from Ansible `2.10` you have two options

- Use Ansible community package (Ansible Core + community Collections). Versions follow semantic versioning, the next version is `3.0` (`6.2` being the latest version available).
- Use `ansible-core` and then add selected Collections individually. Versions does not follow semantic versioning and a the next version is `2.11` (latest being `2.13.2`)

*References*

- [Announcing the Community Ansible 3.0.0 Package](https://www.ansible.com/blog/announcing-the-community-ansible-3.0.0-package)
- [Ansible 3.0.0 Q&A](https://www.ansible.com/blog/ansible-3.0.0-qa)
- [Ansible releases and maintenance](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/release_and_maintenance.html)

## Fully Qualified Collection Names (FQCN)

- In `2.10` and above you should use the FQCN (for example `ansible.builtin.copy`) even if the short name are still usable for the modules available in `2.9` thanks to a mapping.
- In `2.9` you should use short names because this is the documented way of using builtin modules.

Comment: Thak you for your answer!
Unfortunately I still have to use 2.9.7 in some environments. If I write ansible.builtin.xxx, will it work in 2.9.7 or 2.10 or later?
Why can I use ansible.builtin.copy instead of copy in 2.9.7...?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Using fully qualified collection names is strongly advised in `2.10`. In `2.9` you should stick to short names even if FQCNs should work in most cases, see this PR for detail https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/71824